# Multi Tenant WebApp + WebApi + Windows Azure Active Directory Issue

Tags: azure, asp.net-web-api, azure-web-app-service, azure-active-directory

So, I *thought* I had this all working until I deployed to a new set of environments.  I have a webapp that's authenticating just fine with multi-tenant WAAD users.  But when I try to hit the webapp from an HttpClient after authenticating via AcquireTokenAsync **I always get the login page** as the result.

The only concrete thing I have to go in is the fact that the on-boarding process never seems to complete.  The login prompt **always** asks me to give the WebApp and Native Client permissions.

I've triple checked client ids, tenants, app id urls, etc.  Is there anything else to investigate?  I hit this snag once before only for it to just start working :(

**Edit #1**: Webapp + api works just fine via the normal cookies, just seems to completely ignore the Bearer token I'm setting?

Comment: What's the question?  Not sure what problem you're asking help with

Comment: I guess my question (out of frustration) is why would the WebApi controllers are seemingly ignoring the Bearer token I'm passing them.  I don't even see the calls to the WebApi at all, like some filter is redirecting to the login page even before the service is hit or the user is authenticated.

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out I had set the Audience on the WindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearer object incorrectly so the token was never valid...